# Sending emails to multiple recipients in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm creating a Support Ticketing System.

I need some help on creating teams from my `User` table, so users of the app can assign tickets to team, and the whole team can get an email once a ticket is created and they belong to that team.

I have `Department`, `Ticket` and `User` models.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a Team model to your application.

Comment: I thought about it. Any ideas, how would i call the teams users on my :to in the mailer afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

1. one user can belong to only one team, and
2. one ticket is assigned to one team.

the following  class structure could work:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :tickets
end
```

This allows for the following:

```
t = Ticket.find(...) # Find a specific ticket with id
t.team # The team assigned to which the ticket is assigned to
t.team.users  # Users belonging to that team
t.team.users.map(&:email)  # Array of emails for the users belonging to that team, assuming there is an email field in the `User` model.
```